# I intended to send some information and their value to fill up the columns in the database

Tags: php, mysql

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
exit;


$errors = [];

$title = '';
$price = '';
$description = '';
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].'<br>';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {}
$title = isset($_POST ['title']);//test
$description = isset($_POST['description']);
$price =isset ($_POST ['price']);
$date = date ('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if (!$title) {
    $errors[] = 'product title is required';

}
if (!$price) {
    $errors[] = 'product price is required';
}

$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO products (title, image, description, price, create_date)       
               VALUE (:title, :image, :description, :price, :date)");
$statement->bindValue(':title', $title);
$statement->bindValue(':image', '');
$statement->bindValue(':description', $description);
$statement->bindValue(':price', $price);
$statement->bindValue(':date', $date);
$statement->execute();
?>
```

I intended to send some information and their value to fill up the columns in the database. Such information as title, image ,description ,and price. But after sending the information, their values wasn't reflected on the database.
The columns were created with just date and time recorded on each while other values such as title ,description and price wasn't recorded on the columns

```
Please I need help
```

Comment: The `isset()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset) you are using will only return true/false. Depending on your PHP version, you probably meant `$title = $_POST['title'] ?? '';`

Comment: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {}` - That statement does nothing. You should put all the DB code (and you accessing the `$_POST` variable) inside the if.

Comment: Hey, dude, you can `var_dump` the variable's value that you want to insert into the database before the `$pdo` statement. Then you can figure out where the problem is.

Comment: You're also creating errors if the title and price are empty, but you still try to insert the data

Comment: @GuidoFaecke, i tried that earlier ,it was giving me an error message ''undefined arrary key".    someone here suggested the isset() key.

Comment: @MaxwellAni you need to check if $errors is empty before inserting new information to the database.

Comment: You should have something like this `if(empty($errors)){
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO products (title, image, description, price, create_date)       
               VALUE (:title, :image, :description, :price, :date)");
$statement->bindValue(':title', $title);
$statement->bindValue(':image', '');
$statement->bindValue(':description', $description);
$statement->bindValue(':price', $price);
$statement->bindValue(':date', $date);
$statement->execute();
}`